# Priorities: Tefillah & Tachanun vs Tefillah w/o

Tags: tefilla, priorities, tachanun, mincha-afternoon-prayer

In my synagogue, Mincha ketana is always right before sunset.By the time the Sh"tz finishes, it is past sunset and there is no Tachanun.
I can go to Mincha gedola with Tachnun at a different place.
I do know there is a pro for Mincha ketana, being at the time of Kurban Ha'Tamid.
However, I have never heard of an importance of having Tachanun.

Similarly, 2 synagogue have Tefillah, one with Tachanun and one w/o for whatever reason, is there a preference to go to the one with?

Comment: http://www.hakotel.org.il/hebrew/ask-the-rav/view-question.asp?id=232&page=7&keyword=&x_category=

Comment: @DanF Nothing wrong, I have never known I can say it by myself (and still,not saying is sort of the minhag I used to have). Now I'm simply interested to know if there is some sort of importance in having Tachanun.

Comment: @Zeev Is that a joke? Of course there's importance to Tachanun. That's _why_ Chazal instituted that we say it. We don't just do it for funsies.

Comment: @Zeev Re the recent edit: the minyan appears not to be following [Shulchan Arukh and standard Halacha](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=286) which mandates using a Heichi Kedusha if the Chazzan won't finish in time. Just another reason to avoid this Minyan which doesn't seem to know what it's doing.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'll try to make it clearer. Mincha is 10 minutes before the earliest sunset in the week. Assuming we do have a minhag of not saying Tachanun after sunset, I didn't check if the Sh"tz actually finishes after, I remember being told that is the reason. Bottom line, there is never Tachanun in Mincha ketana there. Of course there is importance in saying it, but I didn't hear it is prioritized over a minyan w/o.

Comment: @Zeev If it has important, then given two minyans with ALL ELSE EQUAL, then by definition you choose the one that says it. Isn't that straightforward?